# non-stopping program in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to do a non-stopping program in PHP? For example, using 2% of processor and some memory all of the time. If it's not possible, can you tell me what direction I should be looking for c++ non-stopping program (on UNIX server) and how to pass variables from PHP to c++.

EDIT:

First: I have max execution time which is stopping it (but I need it for other scripts in problem of bugs).

Second: I don't want to burn server so while true it's not the best idea (it have to have some max memory and processor usage).

Comment: Yes, and from CLI it is non-stopping by default unless it ends normally

Comment: You could, if you really wanted. <? while(true); ?> would run forever.

Comment: yes. of course but it would take all the memory and  and the others scripts should have max execution time

Comment: @JakubTruneček: Read the question: the last sentence, in particular. To the OP: Why not write a daemon in C(++)?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: true, I'm sorry

Comment: :) We've all been there, too eager to comment...

Comment: I removed the C++ tag, since the daemon part is not really what this question is asking (and daemons can be written in any other language aswell).

Comment: Going through my old questions, I've found this one. Basically if you are looking for non-stoping program in php it means that almost for sure you are doing something wrong :). It's better to use the cron jobs. It's very useful for for example synchronization plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CLI](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.commandline.php)

Create your `php` file and run it on the `command line`, it won't stop unless the code ends

You can limit the memory usage: `php -d memory_limit=128M my_script.php` this is changing `php.ini` directives so you can edit on your own instead of defining it every time

Comment: can i give some max processor usage or memory?

Comment: can i give processor usage to?

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
// run-forever.php
while(true) {
    // your executive code
    usleep(500) // time in us - something like yield to not ocupy the CPU
}
```

and then you can run: `php run-forever.php`

Answer (score -1):

btw if you tend to use web based php you'll have to define  `set_time_limit(0);` before a while loop.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Question is : Is it possible to do a non-stopping program in PHP? And the answers were given ... except the one important point, which i mentioned. This is an answer because with time limit php will break execution. My answer is indeed the one real exact answer. You can create loops in many other ways  that is a programming option but this setting is critical to keep the loop not broken.